# Is there a way to setup a "Work Profile" for an arbitrary Exchange account?

Tags: gmail, exchange, restricted-profiles

I've worked at companies in the past where it was possible on Android to setup a "work profile" which remained totally separate from the personal profile. This meant separate apps for things like Gmail, Calendar, Docs, etc. that were totally isolated from each other.

The benefit of this is that the company can delete the entire work profile if they need to without touching any of the personal apps and data on the device.

If I go to setup a new Exchange account for a Microsoft domain, it asks me to give it full and *total* control of my device and the ability to delete everything at the discretion of the IT administration of the organization.

Is there a "work profile" mode for setting up a Gmail Exchange account or a way to do this with the Microsoft apps?

I'm on Android 9 on an original Pixel 1.